# How to override cypress json file in a specific spec?

Tags: json, overriding, cypress, config

[image]

How to override cypress json file in a specific spec?
it('', {
chromeWebSecurity: false
}, () => {

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Cypress.config()` for this:

```js
it('some Test', () => {
  Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity', false)
  //Rest of the test
})
```

Comment: `cy.log(Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity')) // true`
`Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity', false);`
`cy.log(Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity')) // false`

Tried this way but not affect to the test result, still fail when accessing cross-origin iframes that are embedded in the application. 

[link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false)